# Private attribute in class makes typed public attributes undefined

Tags: raku

I'm writing a class that looks like this:

```
class ListenSocket is Tap {
    has         $!VMIO;
    has Promise $.socket-host;
    has Promise $.socket-port;

    method new(&on-close, Mu :$VMIO, Promise :$socket-host, Promise :$socket-port) {
        self.bless: :&on-close, :$VMIO, :$socket-host, :$socket-port;
    }

    submethod BUILD(Mu :$!VMIO) { }
}
```

When I try to construct the class with defined Promises for `$socket-host` and `$socket-port`, their attributes in the class end up becoming undefined for whatever reason. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Probably due to the empty method BUILD you have. `bless` actually calls it. If your definition is so straightforward, it's probably better if you don't define anything, or leave it to BUILD instead of defining `new`

Comment: This probably works better if you change the name of `BUILD` to `TWEAK`

Comment: Neither of these work since `&on-close` is a private member of `Tap`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I should have started off with what Liz wrote. Switch `BUILD` to `TWEAK`. Then the default `BUILD` will do its thing and your socket attributes will get correctly initialized.

The next problem is `&on-close`. See [Lizmat's answer to **Constructors in subclases**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547759/perl6-constructors-in-subclases/44552948#44552948) showing how to deal with that if you can modify the superclass (`Tap` in this case) or [Jonathan's authoritative answer to **Inheriting private attributes in Perl 6**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50031896/1077672) (which is about any access whatsoever to another class's attributes) showing you're out of luck if you *can't* modify the superclass.

---

Note that the above two issues aren't really about "private attributes" in a class making "public attributes" undefined. Nor are types relevant.

**All** attributes are technically private. The private/public distinction is about whether there's a public *accessor* for a private attribute.

Your custom `BUILD` is only initializing `$!VMIO`, the one that doesn't have a public accessor. You have neglected to initialize `$!socket-host` and `$!socket-port`, the attributes that *do* have public accessors (due to use of [the public accessor twigil `.`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#The_._twigil) when declaring them).

You presumably wrote a custom `BUILD` because the default `BUILD` only initializes attributes with public accessors. But if you do that you are taking on full responsibility for object construction and you must initialize all attributes that you want initialized.

It's better to write a [`TWEAK`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#index-entry-TWEAK). Then you can just deal with the attributes *without* public accessors. A `TWEAK` just *adds further initialization* to the `BUILD`, which for the default `BUILD` is just initialization of the attributes *with* public accessors.

Comment: This still doesn't work for `$!VMIO`, even when I add it to `BUILD`. It does work for `$.socket-host` and `$.socket-port` though

Comment: However adding `$!VMIO` and `$.socket-port` to `BUILD` does fix this, so if you could edit your answer that'd be great

Comment: *`$!VMIO` and `$.socket-port` for the first comment

Comment: Answer completely rewritten.